# Autodesk forge viewer, model properties and model coordination ID relationships

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

It is not clear for me the relationship between the  identifiers used in the Model Coordination API and the ones used in the Model Properties API:

- loid: (Model coordination API)
- lvid: (model coordination API)
- svf2Id:(Model properties API)
- databaseId: (Model properties API)

let's say  I have some objects with specific propery values and I have found those object by means of the Model properties API.
Then I have some clashes and I would like to know if any of the elements involved in the clashes belongs to the previous group of elements.
Is there any relationship between the loid and the svf2Id for example? how could I achieve this task?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the difference between the ids you are asking:

- The `loid` of Model coordination API is the stable object id, but it's just for our service use internally. It's nothing related to what you want, unfortunately. (Same as `roid`)
- The `lvid` of model coordination API) is the object dbId in SVF format,  which matches with the `lmvId` in Model Properties query results within the exact same model file version in Document Management, so the same version which clashed must be the one which is queried via the Model Properties API.
- The `lmvId` of of Model properties API is dbId for this object in the SVF format.
- The `svf2Id` of Model properties API is dbId for this object in the Forge viewer when loading the model in SVF2 format and when you translated the model to SVF2 format.
- The `databaseId` of Model properties API is the index manifest key for the PDB resource that contains this row for Model properties API.

Therefore, you must use the `lvid` and `rvid`, which match with the `lmvId` in Model Properties query results.